# Getting around lack of inline asm using MSVC10 x64

Tags: c, assembly, 64-bit

I'm trying to write a simple device driver for Windows 7 x64 using the latest Windows Driver Kit that will parse the Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT) and print the contents. I plan on doing this by using the SIDT (store IDT) assembly instruction, however MSVC does not allow you to use inline asm when compiling for x64. Is there any way to get around this restriction? I checked MSDN and it said to look at the compiler intrinsics, but I don't believe there is an intrinsic available that does what I need.

The code I intended to use:

```
__asm sidt, idt_info     // Where idt_info is a suitable struct
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an intrinsic available for it, [__sidt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983358.aspx).

Comment: Well I sure feel stupid for missing that, thank you very much.